# LDAP interface for non-technical employees?

Tags: email, ldap, address-book

I'm looking to set up [*OpenLDAP*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLDAP) on our company server to act as an [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)-based company-wide address book, but I can't find any decent user interfaces for it.

Whilst I'm sure I could manage the DIT without too much trouble, what I'm really looking for is a simple interface that a non-technical employee (say a receptionist) could use to add/edit contacts, search via company etc. Something that just looks like a basic address book.

*Bonus points if it can import contacts from [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [LDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) files.*

Any thoughts, or am I better off using something that's not LDAP based?